# Is there a way to have previous/next links at the bottom of shiny presentations?

Tags: shiny, knitr, presentation, ioslides

I am working in RStudio and creating a markdown Shiny presentation (which I believe uses IOslides).

Currently the generated presentation doesn't have any navigational help, the user has to know they need to use left/right arrows to move to the next or previous slides. Even when deployed to server I don't see any arrows at the bottom of presentations.

I have searched [through documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html) and here to see if this is possible, but can't seem to find anything.

Is there some setting to include a Previous/Next type link at the bottom of every slide?

Process to create my presentation in R Studio:

New file > R Markdown > Shiny > Shiny presentation

The issue occurs even with the sample code when creating a new file - there are no navigation arrows

Published example (where there are no navigation arrows):

https://regolith.shinyapps.io/test

And the sample code (as generated by R studio):

````
---
title: "test"
author: ""
date: "24 January 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Shiny Presentation

This R Markdown presentation is made interactive using Shiny. The viewers of the presentation can change the assumptions underlying what's presented and see the results immediately. 

To learn more, see [Interactive Documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

## Interactive Plot

```{r eruptions}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```

## Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## R Output

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: I added code and published app above using the sample code created in R studio